# Visual Studio: Command line error D8016: '/Ox' and '/RTC' command-line options are incompatible

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to write C++ project. I was trying to use O2 or Ox optimization when building the project. But it prompted up an error that
" cl: command line error D8016:'/Ox' and '/RTC' command-line options are incompatible."

I tried to find the solution from the internet, but it didn't work for me.

Hope some one could give me a hand.

Best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first, your error code is wrong. You probably made a mistake when posting it as it should be D8016, not D0816. Hopefully, you have not done other mistakes that could mislead us...

Other than that, the error message is clear:

> Visual Studio: Command line error D0816: '/Ox' and '/RTC' command-line options are incompatible

But you can also see the description of this error type in here:

[Command-Line Error D8016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/command-line-error-d8016?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170)

The short answer - as the error says -, you cannot use both of them simultaneously. The life is full of compromise, you will need to select either of them whichever is more important for you.

The solution is to turn off `/RTC` for the release build, and only use it for the debug builds to find issues. See the [corresponding documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/rtc-run-time-error-checks?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170), that is also available from the first link above, for more details:

> Run-time error checks are a way for you to find problems in your running code; for more information, see How to: Use Native Run-Time Checks.
>
> If you compile your program at the command line using any of the `/RTC` compiler options, any pragma optimize instructions in your code will silently fail. This is because run-time error checks are not valid in a release (optimized) build.
>
> You should use `/RTC` for development builds; `/RTC` should not be used for a retail build. `/RTC` cannot be used with compiler optimizations (/O Options (Optimize Code)). A program image built with `/RTC` will be slightly larger and slightly slower than an image built with `/Od` (up to 5 percent slower than an `/Od` build).

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typo in my title. I want to use /OX. How could I do it?

Comment: Hi Laszlo, I simply turn the /STC off in VS and run it without debugging. I am quite new with the Visual Studio. Thanks! Do you mind if I mark @txtechelp as the correct answer? Since he/she has less point..I

Comment: @user3342797: That is alright. :) Assuming you meant turning `/RTC` off as opposed to `/STC`.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a great experience with my first question at StackoverFlow, I love this place because of people like you.

Comment: I have case where `/OUT:` is mingled with `/O` leading to the D8016 error where there is not.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/rtc-run-time-error-checks?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170): you can't use the `/RTC` with [`/O` Options (Optimize Code)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/o-options-optimize-code?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170).

If you want to use optimizations, turn off the `/RTC` flag (or turn off optimizations of your want run time checks).

Or to avoid it all, create separate build configurations that have the separate flags as needed (like a debug and release build).

Comment: Thanks for your information, I knew it could not use them concurrently.But How could I solve it? I don't need to debug my code.

Comment: The MSDN docs explains how to turn it 'off' in VS, if your building from the command line then just remove the `/RTC` flag

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am not familiar with building with command line with VS. I simply turn the /STC 'off'. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

To turn `/RTC` off via GUI, just go to Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation:

[image]

and set "Basic Runtime Checks" to default.

---

... or remove `/RTC` from the command line if built via command line interface

---

... or disable it in the .vcxproj file, by changing

```
<BasicRuntimeChecks>EnableFastChecks</BasicRuntimeChecks>
```

to

```
<BasicRuntimeChecks>Default</BasicRuntimeChecks>
```

in the corresponding Configuration.